# Netty TCP Ping Pong performance numbers using EPoll

Tags: java, netty, nio, epoll, low-latency

I'm considering Netty for my tier 1 US bank algo trading project. However I cannot find any performance numbers for a simple ping-pong TCP test:

- Client sends a 64-byte message to Server
- Server receives the message and sends back to the client
- Client calculates the latency time for the round-trip

I know that EPoll for Linux is the fastest NIO implementation.

My question in: What is the average time, min time and max time that Netty can deliver for a 64-byte message round-trip on my 4Ghz processor? I will be testing localhost/loopback first.

Answer (score 0):

As always there is no "fits all answer" here. You will need to run a benchmark by yourself. The outcome depends highly on OS, Kernel, Settings, Code itself etc.